# Insert something before an enumeration

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I started a new Word document and directly started an numbered enumeration like this

> 1. first
> 2. second

Now I am unable to insert something before the enumeration, I can only position the cursor in front of "first", but not before the "1". So, how can I insert text before the enumeration? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word 2010 doesn't do that, and that's what I have. So, I'm not able to test my theory.

Put the cursor in front of **first**, and press enter. That should give you

1. 
2. first
3. second

Put the cursor back to the right of **1.**, and hit backspace. You should end up with a blank line and your original list.

Comment: ah thanks, I somehow forgot I could just delete the new 1 ;-) I am on Word 2007, but your theory worked :-)